# How to give rigorous proofs of these two limit statements?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function $F(x)$. Then how to rigorously prove the following two limit statements?

1. $\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x) = 0$.
2. $\lim_{x \to + \infty} F(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember this following result:

**Theorem** A probability $P$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and a converging sequence of sets $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ with limit $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n) = P(A)$

In particular you have that if $A_n \to \Omega \implies P(A_n) \to 1$ and $A_n \to \emptyset \implies P(A_n) \to 0$.

---

A CDF of a probability $P^X$ is defined by: $F(x) := P^X((-\infty,x])$

Remember also that $P^X(A) = P(X^{-1}(A))$ so it's clear that $P^X(\mathbb{R}) = P(\Omega) = 1$ and $P^X(\emptyset) = P(\emptyset) = 1$.

When $x \to \infty$ the sequence $(-\infty,x]$ converge to $\mathbb{R}$ and when $x \to -\infty$ the sequence $(-\infty,x]$ converge to $\emptyset$. So, remebering the previous result you have:

- $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} P^X((-\infty,x]) = P^X(\mathbb{R}) = 1$
- $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} P^X((-\infty,x]) =  P^X(\emptyset) = 0$

This result by the way is valid for all CDF of probability defined on real line and not only for those induced by a real random variable.

EDIT: These are main steps for the proof, if you need more details just ask!

Comment: Nice! This is the standard way for proving that ;-)

Comment: What is a *converging sequence of sets* ? I do not remember I ever encountered this notion.

Comment: Emar, I'm afraid the symbolism you use is not clear enough to me.

Comment: @Siméon Well, a converging sequence of sets is a sequence of sets such as the indicator function converges pointwise, thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{A_n} = 1_A$. The set $A$ Is said to be the limit of that sequence. For more info on sequences of sets take a look for example [here](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math4381/setseq.pdf).

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I'm really sorry, but this is the standard measure theoretic framework needed to prove rigorously these statements, as you required. If you tell me exactly what is not clear to you I try to explain better! Anyway think intuitively to it, if $x$ Increases, the set $(\infty,x]$ tends to the entire real line, $\mathbb{R}$, which has probability 1. The same in the other case.

Answer (score 0):

The second limit (2) just represents $\Pr(x\in\mathbb{R})$.

For the first limit (1), define $G(x) = 1 - F(-x)$ and note that $G$ is also a cumulative distribution function.  Then using (2), we then have 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F(x)= \lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}F(-y)=1-\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}(1-F(-y))=1-\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}G(y)=1-1=0$$

Comment: paw88789, I think you would like to edit your answer for possible typing errors.

Comment: @Saaqib Mahmud. Yes, thank you, you're right.  I have made the edits.